# Why do different solvers in Logistic Regression(sklearn) give different results?

Tags: logistic-regression

I was doing my ML homework and found that LogisticRegression (sklearn) without regularization gives different results depending on whether the data is normalized or not. This is strange, because normalization is just a linear transformation.

```
ct = ColumnTransformer([
    ('ohe', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), cat_features),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler(), number_features)
    ], remainder='passthrough')

pipe3 = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('ct', ct),
    ('logreg', LogisticRegression(penalty=None, max_iter=1000, solver='lbfgs'))
])

lazy_test(pipe3)
```

The result:

```
Train:   0.7721413945410982
Test:    0.7659698438358779
```

Without standartization:

```
ct = ColumnTransformer([
    ('ohe', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), cat_features)
    ], remainder='passthrough')

pipe3 = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('ct', ct),
    ('logreg', LogisticRegression(penalty=None, max_iter=1000, solver='lbfgs'))
])

lazy_test(pipe3)
```

The result:

```
Train:   0.4624171576873345
Test:    0.45033180449094434
```

How to explain it? I found out that if I use another solver like newton-cg the result is correct.

```
ct = ColumnTransformer([
    ('ohe', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), cat_features)
    ], remainder='passthrough')

pipe3 = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('ct', ct),
    ('logreg', LogisticRegression(penalty=None, max_iter=1000, solver='newton-cg'))
])

lazy_test(pipe3)
```

The result:

```
Train:   0.7721375106245625
Test:    0.7659845638626798
```